# Is it possible that async/await can block a process?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have two handlers:

```
    app.action('some_route', async (ctx, next) => {

        await new Promise((resolve) => {

            setTimeout(resolve, 50000000)

        })


        await ctx.answer("Hello");
   })
```

and the second one:

```
    app.action('another_route', async (ctx, next) => {

        await ctx.answer("Hello");

    })
```

When I make the first request to "`some_route`" I don't get reply, because of `await` and `timeout`

But when I make the second request to "`another_route`" the app doesn't respond as well, because it's blocked by the first `await`

The question is:

Does `async/await` work this blocking way or it's a problem of a library I use?

Comment: It's definitely not the async functions themselves blocking. What library is `app.action`?

Comment: @snek It's Telegraf - a library for working with Telegram bot API

Comment: since that library handles messages, which have an explicit order, it won't process the next message until the previous one has been handled.

Comment: @snek I found the problem. If you are interested: the problem is related to long pooling connection. It firstly handles all updates and only then makes another request

Comment: Keep attention that nodejs is a single thread technology. Parrlelism is archieved by third party tools these generate callbacks into the main stack through quee. So few actions are not able to be processed in the single thread. If you need this you have to check solutions these provide such functionality. The simplest one is to run few threads.